# C++ While statement won't stop repeating after the first time

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I'm attempting to write code for a programming class, and I for some reason find that it will only not repeat if your first response to the question is "n." Otherwise, it will continue to repeat no matter what you enter.

```
while (again == 'y')
{
cout << endl << endl;

//Header Art
cout << "     .\'(     .-./(     )\\.-.        .\'(     /`-.      /`-.  .-,.-.,-.   )\\.--.  \n";
cout << " ,\') \\  )  ,\'     )  ,\' ,-,_)   ,\') \\  )  ,\' _  \\   ,\' _  \\ ) ,, ,. (  (   ._.\' \n";
cout << "(  \'-\' (  (  .-, (  (  .   __  (  /(/ /  (  \'-\' (  (  \'-\' ( \\( |(  )/   `-.`.   \n";
cout << " ) .-.  )  ) \'._\\ )  ) \'._\\ _)  )    (    )   _  )  ) ,_ .\'    ) \\     ,_ (  \\  \n";
cout << "(  ,  ) \\ (  ,   (  (  ,   (   (  .\'\\ \\  (  ,\' ) \\ (  \' ) \\    \\ (    (  \'.)  ) \n";
cout << " )/    )/  )/ ._.\'   )/\'._.\'    )/   )/   )/    )/  )/   )/     )/     \'._,_.\'  \n";

cout << endl;

 //Variables
 int TuitionBill, BoardBill, TotalBill;

 char tuition, board, again;

 cout << "Welcome to Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry!\n\n";

 cout << "Please input 'I' if you are in-country or 'O' if you are out of country\n";
 cin >> tuition;

 cout << endl << endl;

 cout << "Please input 'Y' if you will be staying in one of the four houses\n and 'N' if you will be hiding out in the Shrieking Shack.\n";
 cin >> board;

 cout << endl << endl;

 switch (tuition)
 {
     case 'I':
     TuitionBill = 3000;
     if (board == 'Y')
     BoardBill = 2500;
     else if (board == 'N')
     BoardBill = 0;
    TotalBill = TuitionBill + BoardBill;

    cout << "Your total bill for the semester is $" << TotalBill;

    break;

    case 'O':

     TuitionBill = 4500;
     if (board == 'Y')
     BoardBill = 3500;
     else if (board == 'N');
     BoardBill = 0;
    TotalBill = TuitionBill + BoardBill;

    cout << "Your total bill for the semester is $" << TotalBill;

    break;

    default:
    cout << "That answer is invalid. Please input only an 'I' or an 'O.'";
 }

 cout << endl << endl;

 cout << "Would you like to run the program again? (y/n)\n";
 cin >> again;
```

If anyone could help, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: It shouldn't be the main problem, but I think the semicolon in `else if (board == 'N');` should be removed.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? What have you found?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: This isn't the complete code so it's hard to tell.  However, you should compile with the warning level as high as it will go, and pay attention to all the warnings.  There should be something in there about the variable `again`.

Comment: You mention loops.  Your first statement is a loop.  The block opens at line 2, yet it never closes..

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the definition of `again` in the loop.
It prevents the `again` evaluated in the condition of `while` from being updated.